# Subversion svn:ignore after a commit - files are not iggnore

Tags: svn, version-control, ignore

I've been trying to ignore particular files and directories in order to prevent local modifications being submitted to repository.

The problem I am having is that **once a file has been committed to a repository, you cannot *then* ignore it**.

```
svn propset svn:ignore '*' ./stuff
```

If the files in the ./stuff folder have already been added and committed, they are not ignored for future commits. I find I often want to ignore particular files at the beginning of a project but cannot **as these directories are not working copies** so i'm doing

```
svn add *
svn revert fileIWantToIgnore.ext
svn propset svn:ignore 'fileIWantToIgnore.ext' .
```

This is a bit of a laborious process. What would be your suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Protect files from svn commit.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779293/protect-files-from-svn-commit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is what it is supposed to do, but you could try these.

Create a pre-commit hook script that reject the commit when a specific property is being added. You can then add this property to files in the working copy to prevent commits.

TortoiseSVN will exclude files in the special changelist "ignore-on-commit". However, this is not honored by the SVN command-line client.

[SVN: Is there a way to mark a file as "do not commit"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/635446/537980)

Answer (score 5):

Delete the files you wanted to ignore but were committed.
Commit the version with the files deleted. 
Restore the files to your source, and add the property svn:ignore now.

It's not clean but useful

Comment: Thanks you, you made my day :)